# Laravel .env configuration on webserver

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5. On my local computer the app works perfectly but when I upload it to the webserver, it doesn't. I recognized that the problem is with the `.env` file because it works only if I explcitly write these settings to config files in `config` directory. Why?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: I see a message: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.". And when I write config variables directly into config/app.php (and database.php), it works alright.

Comment: More info please: what do your logs say about the "Whoops" error? Find out what the exception is & you'll probably see which value (or values) are missing from you `.env` file.

Comment: Are you deploying to Heroku by the way? Just in case, remember you won't be able to store a .env remotely because of the dynos architecture. In that case you must set your env vars using a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem. Most likely it is caused by PHP settings of the webserver. If you enable showing PHP warnings, you will see that the `putenv()` function is disabled. This can by solved by enabling it (if your server provider supports that) or not using `.env` file and writing contents of this file to custom config files in the `config` directory.